Microsoft Word Content Control Questions
I'm building multi-purpose templates in Microsoft Word. The documents have a fixed structure (e.g., the letterhead template—address block, salutation, body text, signature block) but each piece might have different options (different body text, different address block, etc.). I'm currently using content controls in two ways. First, the various components have content controls (e.g., addressee's name, which is mapped to a content control on the following page's header). Second, each "piece" is accessible using a Building Blocks Gallery content control (e.g., the user clicks on the Address Block Building Blocks Gallery content control to select from the various address blocks).
I have two questions. First, for the non-Building Blocks Gallery content controls, is there a way I can use an outside data source to set the values for those content controls? For example, if users will be writing letters to John Doe at 123 Main Street, Anytown, USA 12345 I'd like to be able to somehow tell Word, "Draft a letter from the letterhead template using John Doe's address information which is available [here]." (Yes, this example is trivial, but in practice there could be a lot more content controls.)
Second, when using the Building Blocks Gallery content controls they appear to universally add an extra paragraph break to the content being inserted. For example, if the building block in question is:

Here's some text that's one paragraph long. It ends with a paragraph break.¶

the Building Blocks Gallery content control will insert the following:

Here's some text that's one paragraph long. It ends with a paragraph break.¶


¶

Users can delete the extra paragraph break, but if I can prevent it that would be even better.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

"Building Blocks Content Control" is not a category I recoginize. There is the "Building Blocks Gallery Content Control." Rather than mapping a CC to have it replicate in the Header, use a StyleRef field.

Word calls/categorizes a lot of these features as Mailings, including looking up address information from a source like a database/excel/outlook: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-mail-merge-for-bulk-email-letters-labels-and-envelopes-f488ed5b-b849-4c11-9cff-932c49474705. The building blocks  themselves can have a paragraph break set in the properties>options>insert content in own paragraph

@CharlesKenyon thanks, I clarified, it is a Building Blocks Gallery content control. I didn't mention anything about the header because none of this is occurring in a header.

@Cpt.Whale all the building blocks include the setting "Insert content only," not "Insert content in its own paragraph," or "Insert content in its own page." I'd love to use mail merge to set the values for the various XML parts (e.g., if I have an XML part called "Name" I'd love to import the item in the name column of an Excel file). Alternately, if there's a way to set up an XML file and say, "Word, look at this XML file to get the XML data to use in this template" that'd work too.

When creating the building block/AutoText do not select the paragraph mark at the end.

The general idea with Word and XML is that if you create your own CustomXMLPart and map your content controls to that, then in principle you can replace the content of the part (with XML with the same structure) and Word will update the  content of the linked controls. But you can only really do that in VBA or using other programming techniques.

So if you are in position to use VBA I can provide some sample code.

Yes, those linked fields are called Merge Fields. You can insert a Merge Field to pull data from a list/excel file/database or whatever you need, and it can look something like this:

Anything that should be automatically pulled from your data like this needs to be a merge field instead of a content control.
More detailed steps: Use mail merge to personalize letters
Word has a bunch of built-in merge field names for recipients and addresses, but you can create custom ones like AmountDue by inserting a Field > Edit field > MergeField > set Field name > OK, and it will be pulled from the matching column in your data
You can generate it for a specific person by using Find Recipient in the Mailings ribbon tab
